# Align and center various elements in a Bootstrap 'row'

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Been having difficulty trying to center vertically a Font Awesome icon, a 2 text line div, and 2 more icons in the same Bootstrap row div. I managed to fake the needed outcome but after hours trying out numerous CSS properties I'd love to hear what the best solutions was.

So the items I need to position vertically centered so those stay that way regardless of the containing element size are the 'fa fa-building-o fa-4x' icon, the 2 lines of text to its right ("X5 Retail Group" and "Company address and contacts"), both are of different font size (which I attempted to achieve with `<h5>` and `<h3>` tags), and the 2 icons to the right.

It was not required to make the sections of a certain height. The line-height property contains a number convenient to me at the moment.

The code was designed for Firefox 39.

Here's a Plunkr link to my html: https://plnkr.co/edit/0BVnHFowRD53KOVoy1KU?p=preview

Below is the .html of the page.

```css
     body {
       padding-top: 20px;
     }
     section#top1 {
       line-height: 40px;
     }
     section#top2 {
       line-height: 80px;
     }
     .monitoring {
       background-color: #E8E8E8;
     }
     .monitoringh4 {
       display: inline;
     }
     .h4buttonlike:hover {
       cursor: pointer;
       font-weight: bold;
     }
     section#top3 {
       line-height: 60px;
     }
     section#top4 {
       line-height: 80px;
     }
     .container {
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       border-radius: 4px;
       margin-bottom: 5px;
     }
     .container .col-md-12 {
       background: #e6e6e6;
       border-radius: 4px;
     }
     .container .logo {
       display: inline;
       margin: auto 0 auto 0;
       width: 80px;
     }
     .container h4 {
       font-size: 1.0em;
       display: inline;
       margin-left: 5px;
       text-align: center;
     }
     section#top1 .container ul {
       display: table;
       margin: auto 0;
       float: right;
     }
     section#top1 .container ul li {
       display: table-cell;
       padding-right: 15px;
     }
     .settings i {
       vertical-align: middle;
     }
     .container i {
       margin-right: 5px;
     }
     .dropdown {
       display: inline;
       margin-left: 5px;
       margin-top: 3px;
     }
     .myclass {
       text-align: right;
     }
     section#top4 .brands {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       display: inline-block;
       /* margin-left: 20px; */
       transform: translate(5%, -55%);
     }
     .exp {
       height: 56px;
       width: 44px;
       display: inline-block;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
     }
     .my-icons {
       position: absolute;
       top: 50%;
       right: 15px;
       transform: translate(-60%, -50%);
       display: inline-block;
     }
```

```html
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



  <section id='top1'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
          <img class='logo' src='http://www.toennies.com/uploads/pics/fTRACE-Logo_02.png'>
          <h4>Company name</h4>
          <ul>
            <li>Total items: 100</li>
            <li style='color: #009900;'>Oline: 82</li>
            <li style='color: #787878;'>Offline: 16</li>
            <li style='color: #FF0000;'>Damaged: 6</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='clearfix'></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id='top2'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-9 monitoring'>
          <div class='monitoringh4'>
            <h4>Monitoring</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <h4 class="dropdown-toggle h4buttonlike" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Reports
            <span class="caret"></span>
           </h4>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#">Report 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Report 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Report 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <h4 class="dropdown-toggle h4buttonlike" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Tune
            <span class="caret"></span>
           </h4>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#">Tune 1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Tune 2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Tune 3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-3 monitoring'>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <h4 class="dropdown-toggle h4buttonlike" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            John Doe (Admin)
            <span class="caret"></span>
           </h4>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#">Jane Doe</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Jack Doe</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Jimmy Doe</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id='top3'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12 settings'>
          <h4><i class="fa fa-desktop fa-2x"></i>Tuneup > Company profile > X5 Retail Group</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id='top4'>
    <div class='container'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
          <div class='exp'><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-4x"></i>
          </div>
          <div class='brands'>
            <h3>X5 Retail Group</h3>
            <h5>Company address and contacts</h5>
          </div>
          <div class='my-icons'>
            <h5><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"> Edit</h5>
            </i>
            <h5><i class="fa fa-print"></i>Print</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please replace your relative links in your snippet with absolute ones. Provide a [mcve] of your problem.

Comment: The links are fixed. Thank you for pointing that out. This was posted late at night. Sorry.

Comment: Edited your code as snippet and removed all the links that were still relative (since you didn't add those, I assumed they weren't important). Recheck and see if anything is missing (custom CSS, maybe?). Now, can you make your question more specific? What are you trying to vertically align? Could you work a bit on the "Minimal" part of your example? Remove anything that is not relevant to the question (CSS, markup).

Comment: In your plnkr, on line 119, you have invalid markup (you're supposed to end the `<h5>` before you end the `<i>`). You have copied the mistake in your code here.

Comment: Thank you. That explains why I had an extra space there. Aprreciate your help only right now I'm stuck with an urgent job.